# How to get list of named MySQL locks held by MySQL client connections

Tags: mysql

For MySQL 5.1, is there a way to get a list of named MySQL "locks" held by MySQL client connections?

I know I can check a specific named lock, if I know the name of the lock. But I want to know how (if possible) to list client connections that are holding (or waiting on) a named lock, and specifically, the name of the lock each client is holding.

I'm asking here about the named locks obtained, released, checked, et al. by the MySQL GET_LOCK, RELEASE_LOCK, IS_FREE_LOCK, and IS_USED_LOCK functions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

(NOTE: I am *not* asking about table locks acquired by LOCK TABLE statement)

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST will show you client connections that are waiting on a lock as their state will be "User lock" but there is no way to find out what the name of the lock is or who it is held by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get a list of clients holding locks, but you should be able to get a list of clients who are actively waiting on a lock using a query like this:

```
select * 
from information_schema.PROCESSLIST 
where state = 'User lock'
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any way to get the name of the lock. I'm sure the name of the lock is in memory somewhere, but MySQL doesn't expose it. Looks like the statement is recorded in the general log, if I have that enabled.